# Query to iterate over array of maps in Firestore (web)

Tags: firebase, react-native, web, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore in my React Native project, and I want to get X document in real time by using .where(), the think is that the field that I'm looking for is inside an array of maps, how can I perform a query to get the document based on the field "r_user_uid"

something like:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("f_invitations").where("invitations.r_user_uid", "==", 12) 
                              .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {...}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following, using `array-contains`, should do the trick.

```
  db.collection('f_invitations')
    .where('invitations', 'array-contains', { r_user_uid: '12' })
    .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
    });
```

---

However note that the entire object in the query shall match the entire object in the array.

In other words, the following does not work:

```
  db.collection('f_invitations')
    .where('invitations', 'array-contains', {
      r_user_uid: '12',
      r_user_name: 'John',
    })
```